# Consecutive dropdown or Progress tracker?

Tags: design, dropdown

Hi there StackExchange!

I am working on designing an analytics portal for an online flyer company. We have multiple client companies, each client company has multiple flyer series, each series has some charts to be displayed.
User must be able to select 1)company, 2)flyer series (depending on a company), 3) see the charts

I really want to stay away from dropdowns (personal preference + difficult to adapt for mobile)

So I am thinking about utilizing some kind of arrow preference tracker, like the one briefly sketched:
[image: Scheme]
Each arrow will have it's own view below, and final view will contain all the charts.

What do you think? Is this a good solution? What are the common practices?

Comment: Welcome to UXSE : )  Your arrows give a strong sense of sequence, but is the operation always done sequentially? Also, and in general, what is the overall nature of this process? You've mentioned what the user needs to select, but not why, and this is often crucial. What's the use case here? What's a user trying to achieve?

Comment: Keep me honest here but I think the user needs to select company and the flyer series associated with their company so they can see some analysis on the flyer performance. Why are you trying to avoid drop downs? Do you have long lists to handle? Are you optimizing for mobile usage?

Comment: How will the arrows work better in mobile view compare to the dropdowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there are just two actual steps:

- picking a company,
- and picking a flyer series.

While statistics observing is just a subsequent result of previous operations. I would suggest to separate these steps.

Additionally, I would recommend to use combo-boxes instead of progress steps. They should work better since the steps seem to be quite trivial.

Applying the aforementioned suggestions, the resulting layout would look like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb5BFX.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>